# roles de usuario con mvc en php

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy intentando dar acceso a un usuario según su rol, tengo 2 tipo uno Administrador con id 1 y Cliente con id 2, hasta el momento valido el usuario y contraseña. por lo que el Cliente puede ingresar a la parte administrativa, y quiero que solo tenga acceso a la vista del Cliente

Esta es mi funcion en el Model:
public function Verificar($usuario, $contrasena) {

```
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND contrasena = ?" ;
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array($usuario, $contrasena));

        $UsuarioDatos = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if ($UsuarioDatos == NULL) {

            return FALSE;

        } else {

            return TRUE;

        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y este es el controlador del Login:

```
public function Autenticar() {

    $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = ($_REQUEST[('contrasena')]);
    $validar = $this->model->Verificar($usuario, $contrasena);
    if ($validar) {
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
        $_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu']=$validar['idCategoriaUsu'];
        $_SESSION['Iniciada']='true';


       if($_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu'] == 1){

        header('Location:index.php?c=Home');
       }
       else {

        header('Location:index.php?c=ClienteNormal');
       }
    } else {

        header('Location: index.php?c=Login&error=true');
    }
}
```

lo que pasa es que no valida el `if($_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu']==1)` y pasa al `else header('Location:index.php?c=ClienteNormal');` he intentado y no lo logro hacer

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que estas retornando `true` o `false` pero no la información de usuario:

```
if ($UsuarioDatos == NULL) {

    return FALSE;

} else {

    return TRUE;

}
```

Por lo tanto cuando llamas a `Verificar()` la variable `$validar` contiene solo `true` o `false`:

```
// aqui validar contiene true o false

$validar = $this->model->Verificar($usuario, $contrasena);
if ($validar) {
    $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;

// por lo tanto $validar['idCategoriaUsu'] posiblemente contenga un null 

    $_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu']=$validar['idCategoriaUsu'];
    $_SESSION['Iniciada']='true';
```

debes de retornar `$UsuarioDatos` que contiene el objeto con los datos del usuario.